# writing an R function

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I want to write a R function that give me the value on 10th percentile of observations. I want to use this function with `sapply`. Like for `mean`, `sapply` is

```
sapply(1 : n, function(i) mean(a1))
```

Say e.g. I have 100 values and 10th percentile of 100 is 10 i want that the value that is on 10th line get printed.

```
X
45
80
70
56
78
78
56
90
35
190
```

.......... up till 100 values

Desired output: print value on 10th line i.e. 190 in the above column

I want the function to calculate first 10th percentile of my 100 observations and later just print the value that come on that position.

Comment: so you only want the 10th value in the list of values `x`? then you can do it simply by `x[10]`

Comment: i want to randomize the sample and extract 10th percentile for every random sample. something like sapply(1 : n, function(i) mean(a1[-i])) here it is calculating mean after deleting one observation so i want it get 10th percentile after deleting one observation

Comment: i see. then say you store the results of the randomised sample in a vector (variable named `X`) or dataframe (column `X`), you can get the 10th percentile by doing `X[10]` for vector or df$X[10] for dataframe

Comment: do u mean like this A <- sapply(1 : n, function(i) z$X[-i]) and then  A[10]

Comment: yes @star, is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: There is more than one way to calculate a quantile, i.e. 10 is not always the solution. check quantile()

Answer (score 0):

The desired function will look like:

```
give_quant_value <- function(vec, quantile) {
    return(vec[quantile(1:length(vec),p=quantile,type=1)])
}
```

where
    - `vec` is vector of interest
    - `quantile` is quantile of interest

Proof:

```
set.seed(42)
a1 <- rnorm(100)
give_quant_value(a1, 0.1)
-0.062714099052421
```

You may read more about `quantile` function while typing `?quantile` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function I wrote: It takes on data as a `data.frame` object.

```
select_percentile<-function(df,n){
  df<-df
  nth<-(n/nrow(df))*100
  return(df[nth,])
}
```

Using data from another answer:

```
 set.seed(42)
   a1 <- rnorm(100)
    df1<-as.data.frame(a1)
    select_percentile(df1,10)
```

Result:

```
#[1] -0.0627141
```